# Trying to pass array element from one array ot other array using pointers...not getting?

Tags: c

Hi friends i am new to C, trying to understand it.

I have these two char arrays one is initialized and other is just declared, i just wanted to copy elements from array state to arr and print it. It compiles, but prints a garbage value....

please help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int i = 0;
     char *arr[3];
     char *state[3] = {"California", "Oregon", "Washington", "Texas"};

     for(i=0; i<3; i++)
     {
         arr[i] = state[i];
         printf("%s\n",arr+i);             
     }

     arr[0] = state[0];

     printf("%s\n",arr[0]);
     system("pause");

     return 0;    
}
```

Comment: You are assigning 4 values to `state` while you declare to hold only 3.

Comment: But only 3 are used, so it shouldn't matter...

Answer (score 7):

Printing `arr+i` is probably not what you want. Instead, you want `arr[i]`, that is one indirection level deeper.

To be concrete, `a[b]` is exactly the same as `*(a+b)`.

Comment: it is still not printing but abruptly exiting terminal window

Comment: did you try to call the program directly from a non-exiting terminal window?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, i think that the way you've initialized `state` is wrong. it should have at most 3 items, but you have given 4 items ("Texas"). change it to:

```
char *state[3] = {"California", "Oregon", "Washington"};
```

in addition to that, the `arr+i` gives the address of the i-th pointer of `arr`. in order to print the string that the i-th pointer in `arr` points to, use `*` like this `*(arr+i)`, which is similar to `arr[i]`.

moreover, please don't use `system("pause");`; `getchar()` does it much better.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have taken the size of both the array as 3, which is wrong. You have four string values in the `state` array so correct array size will be 4.

```
char *arr[4];
char *state[4] = {"California", "Oregon", "Washington", "Texas"};
```

Second, you are printing the address of array "arr" insisted of value.

```
// wrong way
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    arr[i] = state[i];
    printf("%s\n", arr + i);
}
```

Third, you are accessing the first value of array "arr[0]" in a wrong way. Here you have to use pointer to access value.

```
// wrong way
printf("%s\n", arr[0]);
```

Here is the correct way to copy values from one array to another by using pointer.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    char *arr[4];
    char *state[4] = {"California", "Oregon", "Washington", "Texas"};

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = state[i];
        printf("%s\n", *(arr + i));
    }
    arr[0] = state[0];

    printf("%s\n", *(arr));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI, `*(arr)` == `*(arr + 0)` == `arr[0]`.